# Using an arbitrary object for the souceOffset in SourceRecord (Kafka)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Kafka's `SourceRecord` accepts a `sourceOffset`, which is a map between a `String` and an `Object`. This offset can be fetched  with `context.offsetStorageReader().offset(getPartition())`.

```java
SourceRecord​(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?> sourcePartition, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?> sourceOffset, java.lang.String topic, java.lang.Integer partition, Schema valueSchema, java.lang.Object value)
```

Everything works fine if I set the `sourceOffset` to for example a string or a float:

```
SourceRecord(..., Map.of("key", "value"), ...);
```

However, if the value is a custom Object (not a string or float), when fetching the offset I always get `null`. I suspect that's because my object is not serializable, but not sure if i) I'm right with this assumption and ii) how to make it serializable for kafka.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the specific use case you're trying to solve? What's stopping you from serializing that object into a string (for example, json)?

Comment: Actually I could just serialise it into a string, but was trying to use the object so then I don't have to parse the json back. But just found that "Offsets are always defined as Maps of Strings to primitive types, i.e. all types supported by Schema other than Array, Map, and Struct."

Comment: Only requires two lines of Jackson ObjectMapper to serialize and deserialize JSON